# Matlab undefined variable or function error in the output

Tags: arrays, matlab, undefined

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDqpR.png)

Attached image has the question I am working on. Following is the code from my m-file and the output I got in the command window.
M-File Code:

```
function p = PolyEval (n, a, y, x)    
    for i = n+1:2
       p = a(i - 1) + (x + y(i - 1))*a(i);
       a(i-1) = p;
    end
    fprintf('%6.0f %18.8f \n', p);
end
```

Command Window code and output:

```
PolyEval(5, [-1, 3.3, 0, -2.2, 5, -1.6], [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1], 1.53)
```

> Undefined function or variable "p".
>
> Error in PolyEval (line 6)
>       fprintf('%6.0f %18.8f \n', p);

About the code and the question, n is the variable that controls the size of the two arrays, a is a 1-D array consisting of n+1 variables, y is a 1-D array consisting of n variable, and x is a variable that is used in the calculations.

I tested the code algorithm on a piece of paper and it should return a value of 6.65, but in this case it gives me the above error.

Would you guys be able to help me understand why I am getting the error? Please take a look at the image that consists of the question and the equation for which I am trying to write this matlab code.

Comment: Your for loop does not expect what you think it does. When doing it with pen and paper, what are the values for `i` in the different iterations?

Comment: The values of i should be going from 6 down to 2 reducing by 1 in every iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for i = n+1:2` is a loop from 6 to 2 using steps of +1 (which is the default). Whenever the start is higher than the end value, the loop is not executed at all. You want `for i = n+1:-1:2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, the change in the for loop worked, and I also had to initialize a value to p so this was the final code that gave me the correct answer
`
function p = PolyEval (n, a, y, x)    
    
    p = a(n+1);
    for i = n:-1:1
       p = a(i) + (x + y(i))*p;
    end
    fprintf('%6.0f %18.8f \n', p);
end`